# Sudden spike in validation loss

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

So I am doing binary image classification on a small data set *containing 250* images in each class, I am using transfer learning using **Resnet50** as base network architecture and over it I've added 2 hidden layer and one final output layer, after training for 20 epochs, what I've saw is that loss is suddenly increases in initial epoch, I am unable to understand the reason behind it.
**Network architecture** -

```
image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input,include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
last_layer = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = Dense(1000, activation='relu', name='fc1000')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(200, activation='relu', name='fc200')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)
custom_model = Model(image_input, out)
```

I am using *binary_crossentropy, Adam* with default parameters

**Loss** - [image]

**Accuracy** - [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such small class of data, there is definitely chance of overfitting do increase your dataset size and check it out use data augmentation if possible

Comment: I tried to do data augmentation, but there wasn't any significant change though I tried to change my batch size from 8 to 3 and got a perfect loss graph, I still don't know why but I think it's probably because of gradient stucking in local minima.

Comment: reduction in batch size will help if you are using SGD and yes that is one of the reasons